# How to create a data entry that will allow continuous entry of data in columns using UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I wanna input multiple data from userform to my excel worksheet by just using a command button that will enter the next data to the next column.

I've already done inputting data from the userform to the excel worksheet but the problem is i don't know how to move to the next column automatically and input data there.

```
    Private Sub AddLoad_Click()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim AddNew As Range
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Set AddNew = wks.Range("L29:L39").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = txtdist
    AddNew.Offset(1, 0).Value = txttrib
    AddNew.Offset(2, 0).Value = txtpipeod
    AddNew.Offset(3, 0).Value = txtpipethick
    AddNew.Offset(4, 0).Value = txtpipeins
    AddNew.Offset(5, 0).Value = txtctwidth
    AddNew.Offset(6, 0).Value = txtctheight
    AddNew.Offset(7, 0).Value = txtgl
    AddNew.Offset(8, 0).Value = txtat
    AddNew.Offset(9, 0).Value = txtaf
    AddNew.Offset(10, 0).Value = txtaseis
    End Sub
```

I was hoping that someone could help me develop this code so that when I hit my "Add Load" command button, the current date will be saved in column 1 in a specific range in the worksheet and then deleted. Then the next data that I will put will be saved in column 2 of the same range.

Comment: can you explain a bit more on what this line `Set AddNew = wks.Range("L29:L39").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` is doing ?

Comment: Actually I am not so sure. I'm still new to VBA so I just copied that from a youtube tutorial. but his code did not have a specific range. Unlike mine, the input range is only in the range L29:V39.

Comment: So If I am able to understand it correctly, you first want to enter in `Range(L29:V39)` then move along the columns to `M29:M39` ...

Comment: Actually, first column is L29:L39. Second column is N29:N39. The cells are merged across by the way. that's why it jumps from column L to column N then P and so on until column V

Comment: You should add that to the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You want to find the next blank column using this line `Set AddNew = wks.Range("L29:L39").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` but this is not the correct way to do that.

**It should be**

```
Set AddNew = wks.Range("L29").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
```

*Brief:* This will go to the End Cell in Row 29 and move to the last filled cell in the row. And assign the next cell to `AddNew` using Offset of 1 Column.

**Maybe you can try this:**

```
Private Sub AddLoad_Click()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim AddNew As Range
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Set AddNew = wks.Cells(29, wks.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 2)

    If Not AddNew.Column > 12 Then Set AddNew = wks.Range("L29")

    AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = txtdist
    AddNew.Offset(1, 0).Value = txttrib
    AddNew.Offset(2, 0).Value = txtpipeod
    AddNew.Offset(3, 0).Value = txtpipethick
    AddNew.Offset(4, 0).Value = txtpipeins
    AddNew.Offset(5, 0).Value = txtctwidth
    AddNew.Offset(6, 0).Value = txtctheight
    AddNew.Offset(7, 0).Value = txtgl
    AddNew.Offset(8, 0).Value = txtat
    AddNew.Offset(9, 0).Value = txtaf
    AddNew.Offset(10, 0).Value = txtaseis

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this actually. But then the values do not change. When I click "Add Load" the data in the first column still changes even if there existing data already. I think because it's merged, it reads an empty cell then enters that data but shows the data in the same cell. Next step is how to deal with the column skips.

Comment: Change the `.Offset(0, 1)` to `.Offset(0, 2)` and try again @JovicViduya

Comment: It still does not work. When I "Add Load" the First column entry is place in Column C, then E, then G. It does not start at column L. How can I make it start at column L?

Comment: @JovicViduya .. Try the Edited Code in the answer :)